# How we use laravel URL with multiple parameters? Is it necessary to specify each parameter as method argument?Can't we access them through Request?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing, multiparameter

For the time being, I'm trying to use a URL with multiple parameters this way.
For example, I'd pass employee ID, Group ID and current status of the employee in URL using the following pattern.
mydomain.com/en/employee/benefit-status/1-1-enroll

The Route I've defined is as follows:

```
Route::get('{lang}/employee/benefit-status/{slug}', 'EmployeeBenefitController@create');
```

In my controller method, I'm accessing the parameters separately.
`create($lang,$slug)`

This route is working fine.
When I try to access the parameters through Request object:

`create(Request $request)`

Route works fine too but in this case when I try to navigate to any other page.

e.g. If I click a menu item with this link "mydomain.com/en/candidates

The URL get messed up and look something like this:

```
http://hrm.test:8080/GET%20/en/employee/benefit-status/1_1_enroll%20HTTP/1.1Accept:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9Accept-Encoding:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gzip,%20deflateAccept-Language:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20en-US,en;q=0.9Connection:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20keep-aliveContent-Length:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Content-Type:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Cookie:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20laravel_token=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%3D;%20XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InNVRkUzeXB5ZVJaQTM5WmJxNmR1R2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN1dONmVuRU1QRytaQmR4bzZSR1dDVXJKRVptVTdzb0JwajNzMkNFRU1tVUJJc3EwMmpzMms4S3BoclFqbkJ1MCIsIm1hYyI6ImVmZDIxNDA1OGVlY2FmZDkxODg5ZTRkMzE0OWM2NTJlZjYyNjFhNDBmOTk2NzU1M2I0NWZlODM5OGZiMDcyNjgifQ%3D%3D;%20hrm_session=eyJpdiI6IjNjS2Vja1ZDVVpKUlU4YkxYdlwvbzNnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IndCZ0VPZk9OXC9cL01SUGo5VEMwZVJEM0R5VnI0SDBLV1lVWldJemZkODVRRG1yTXpxeXBSdzc4ZUcyMzJ1VnlabiIsIm1hYyI6ImY1NWQ3MGFkYzZjNTljZjVmYzJhMWU5MjRkZjJiN2NhODk0ZTgxNjY3YWZmMjIzYzAzNDFlYWYyNzg0YmI2NjUifQ%3D%3DHost:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hrm.test:8080Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:%201User-Agent:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0;%20Win64;%20x64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/79.0.3945.117%20Safari/537.36Cookie:%20laravel_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsImNzcmYiOiJvSkwzTkVmUEtQZUVWNlhnWVZ4UnNIZm13U2wwcGFjVkNrb0ZQNGtDIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNTc5MzYxMzA2fQ.x1ibu7gHOIMgD73fXs90EdtHnLMb5J4cbgg3uDVYc8s;%20XSRF-TOKEN=oJL3NEfPKPeEV6XgYVxRsHfmwSl0pacVCkoFP4kC;%20hrm_session=MxkRkbJhiLlByPZncb6JqL87ATK0MH8mDLHhKIGg/candidates
```

Comment: How do you assemble those urls?

Comment: I'm trying to assemble them through concatenation.

Comment: I actually want to reduce the size of my url but not sure how.

Comment: I've changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better if you wrote your route like this

```
Route::get('{lang}/employee/benefit-status/{employeeID}/{GoupPlanID}/{status}', 'EmployeeBenefitController@create');
```

The URL get messed up maybe because you didn't used the route in a correct way by providing wrong data.

I prefer to do it in post request since you are inserting this data i guess.

Comment: I actually needes this data to show up a form with specific fields. The fields are dependent on upcoming data. I usually use Modal Windows for such kind of things but my lead told me not to use modal. Use a separate view. I think I should go with this technique coz everything is messed up.

Comment: then how you trigger that route if parameters are in one wildcard only ?

Comment: I have changed my Route as per suggestion but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, the issue has been resolved.
I was only passing the `create(Request $request)` in controller method and was retrieving the parameters by exploding the last segment of request. Once I specified the parameters separately in method. The issue has been resolved. I've edited my question.

Comment: That's why. You can't use Request request if you are having a get request. Request request is just for post request. That's why I suggested to you to separate it so that in your create method  you can access it  easily one by one.   I hope my answer help you. You can upvote it 

Comment: Yes. Thanks, your answer was helpful.
I've upvoted it.